# Does Visual Studio 2019 v16.3.9 fully support C++20?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, c++20

I`ve searched a lot and found different inforamation but unfortuantely could not understand Visual Studio 2019 fully supports C++20 or not!

According to my searches, there are 3 types of information:

1. `Concepts` and `Modules` are fully and partially supported, respectively. There is no support for `Couroutines` and `Ranges`. Also, `Modules` is still at the experimental stage.
2. There is no support except for `Concepts`.
3. All features are fully supported in MSVC and CLANG.

I`ve asked this question because I need to compile some sample code of new features introduced in C++20.

Note: The current and new version of VS2019 (at the time of asking this question) is 16.3.9.

Comment: You say you need to compile code, but have you tried it? Also according to MS itself, no, not fully supported: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2019

Comment: @stijn I have not an installed VS2019 to check whether C++20 is supported or not. Unfortunately, I have not an access to it.

Comment: C++20 is not even finalized yet. Why would any compiler fully support it yet?

Comment: IMHO, clang and gcc are the closest to the new specification. According to [C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/std/status), C++20 is not yet released. So, no compiler can support it completely.

Comment: @Scheff, could you post your comment with more detail in order to mark it as answer.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot provide more detail. That's the most detail, I've available. ;-) (About gcc and clang, that reflects my personal experience: For all the new fancy features, I never had heard about before, I saw samples for gcc and clang. For MSVC (though it really became better in the last years), I mostly heard about complaints that this is not supported or that.) "heard" -> read in SO or other forums.

Comment: You may consider a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) with your findings.

Comment: This might be interesting also: [C++ compiler support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support).

Comment: For what it's worth, changing the MSVC compiler option from `/std:c++17` to `/std:c++latest` changes the value of the `__cplusplus` token from `201703` to `201705` - though I'm not sure what that actually means.

Comment: Btw there are some options to try it with VS without installing it, e.g. get an Appveory account, create a build definition which uses VS2019 and log into it via remote desktop and you can play around with VS.

Comment: You don't need a local copy of Visual Studio to try Visual Studio. There's online services like [Visual Studio Online](https://online.visualstudio.com/) (commercial) or [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/) (free).

Comment: @tan: Compilers will eventually have to implement the International Standard. It is wise to have a full implementation of the upcoming language specification *before* it is handed off to ISO for standardization. After all, if a compiler vendor runs into issues implementing any given feature, it's not going to end well, if they find out after that feature has been voted into the standard. So that's why a compiler would have full support for an upcoming standard, thanks for asking.

Comment: @sch: MSVC has support for coroutines that's much, *much* more mature than any of the competitors. It was introduced in Visual Studio 2015, and has been in production use for **years**.

Comment: @IInspectable: The compiler vendors do not “hand off” a finished standard to ISO.  The standard is a complicated mixture of longstanding practice, vendor-specific extensions, imports from “third-party” libraries like Boost, and wholesale invention by the committee’s experts (including several compiler implementers!) based on more theoretical concerns like optimization and consistency.  The rules for class-type non-type template arguments, for example, got rewritten only two weeks ago, but GCC got the new rules implemented *during* the meeting.

Comment: @dav: I never claimed, that the compiler vendors handed off the draft for standardization. Not sure how you read that into my comment.

Comment: @IInspectable: Sorry—I thought you meant by “ISO” WG21.  If you meant WG21 handing it off to ISO for publication, that is a thing that happens, but again the average number of “conforming” compilers is little more than one for *each* feature.  The committee would have to be idle, or else have its attention badly divided, for a long time to wait on every feature in any one implementation before publication.  Or am I having a failure of imagination and you were aiming at a third meaning?

Comment: @dav: I was responding to Tanveer's comment, who seems to think that it were somehow unreasonable for compilers to implement features of the upcoming language standard prior to it being an international standard. That opinion is unreasonable. It may even be possible, that any given compiler implements *all* C++20 features the OP needs. But since they are secretive about the feature set they actually need, an answer to this question would be of nothing but academic value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Visual Studio 2019 v16.3.9 partially supports C++20.

By changing the MSVC compiler option from `/std:c++17` to `/std:c++latest`, we can use the latest implemented features.

According to the question, type 1 or 2 of gathered information is more close to correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

msvc partially supports concepts, as [there](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c20-concepts-are-here-in-visual-studio-2019-version-16-3/) say

```
Currently, MSVC doesn't support requires-expressions everywhere; they only work in concept definitions and in requires-clauses
```