# error with VS2019 when trying to use to_time_t

Tags: c++

tried to run this code using VS2019:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
int main()
{
    fs::path p = fs::current_path() / "example.bin";
    std::ofstream(p.c_str()).put('a'); // create file
    auto ftime = fs::last_write_time(p);

    // assuming system_clock for this demo
    // note: not true on MSVC or GCC 9; C++20 will allow portable output
    std::time_t cftime = decltype(ftime)::clock::to_time_t(ftime);
    std::cout << "File write time is " << std::asctime(std::localtime(&cftime)) << '\n';

    fs::last_write_time(p, ftime + 1h); // move file write time 1 hour to the future
    ftime = fs::last_write_time(p); // read back from the filesystem

    cftime = decltype(ftime)::clock::to_time_t(ftime);
    std::cout << "File write time is " << std::asctime(std::localtime(&cftime)) << '\n';
    fs::remove(p);
}
```

from:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/last_write_time

but it give this error:

```
class "std::filesystem::_File_time_clock" has no member "to_time_t"
```

can anyone help me please?

Comment: this code doesn't work even in their page example

Comment: Does [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59005741/does-visual-studio-2019-v16-3-9-fully-support-c20) helps to you?

Comment: @Yeheshuah not really but thank you!